# Table field is 4 digit decimal while original data is 2 digit decimal only

Tags: ms-access, vba

I used `Round(Paid,2)` to assign to `Me.Amt`. Result should be round to two digit decimal. But, it is not two digit decimal. I use below code to test.  The `Amt` field is a `Currency` field.  Decimal places is auto.  `Me.Amt` format is currency and decimal places is auto.

Result should be `47340.14`. But, it is `47340.1484` on both `Me.Amt` and table record.

```
    Dim lng As Long
    lng = 4734015
    Me.Amt = 0
    Me.Amt = CSng(l / 100)
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Replace`Me.Amt`with a`Currency`variable and then it shows the conversion error.

Comment: If `Amt` is a currency field, why wouldn't you use `CCur`?

Answer (score 0):

Them problem occurs because of the `CSng` converting the result to a `Single` value having a precision of about 7 decimal digits. A value like `47340.15` cannot be represented with finite number of binary fractional digits.

Just remove `CSng`.

I made a test with

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim lng As Long
    lng = 4734015
    Me.Amt = lng / 100
End Sub
```

and got a result of `47340.15`. If you divide a long value by 100, there is no point in rounding the result to 2 digits as it will never have more than 2 digits.

But note that Access does not support calculations on `Currency` values. If you calculate `CCur(lng) / CCur(100)` the result will be a `Double`. You can test this with `TypeName(CCur(lng) / CCur(100))`. `Double` doubles the precision compared to `Single`.

Answer (score 0):

I change Paid from single to Currency and result is correct now.  Thanks.